# How to shift a column in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to shift a column in a Pandas `DataFrame`, but I haven't been able to find a method to do it from the documentation without rewriting the whole DF. Does anyone know how to do it? 
DataFrame:

```
##    x1   x2
##0  206  214
##1  226  234
##2  245  253
##3  265  272
##4  283  291
```

Desired output:

```
##    x1   x2
##0  206  nan
##1  226  214
##2  245  234
##3  265  253
##4  283  272
##5  nan  291
```

Comment: this should really be an optional flag to the shift function

Answer (score 190, accepted):

```
In [18]: a
Out[18]: 
   x1  x2
0   0   5
1   1   6
2   2   7
3   3   8
4   4   9

In [19]: a['x2'] = a.x2.shift(1)

In [20]: a
Out[20]: 
   x1  x2
0   0 NaN
1   1   5
2   2   6
3   3   7
4   4   8
```

Comment: The result is missing ##5.  Is there an easy way in pandas to extend the index when using shift?

Comment: @WaylonWalker That's called rolling in numpy: `df['x2'] = np.roll(df['x2'], 1)`

Comment: Did anybody figure this out? #5 is still missing

Comment: I have to shift 100 columns in the same way, how can I make a for loop?

Comment: @Johan did you try adding an empty row at the end before you shift it?

Comment: you can add the empty row with something like:
`shift_pos = 1` and,
`df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([[np.nan for i in df.columns] for i in range(shift_pos)], columns=df.columns))`

Answer (score 15):

You need to use `df.shift` here.
`df.shift(i)` shifts the entire dataframe by `i` units down.

So, for `i = 1`:

Input:

```
    x1   x2  
0  206  214  
1  226  234  
2  245  253  
3  265  272    
4  283  291
```

Output:

```
    x1   x2
0  Nan  Nan   
1  206  214  
2  226  234  
3  245  253  
4  265  272
```

So, run this script to get the expected output:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x1': ['206', '226', '245',' 265', '283'],
                   'x2': ['214', '234', '253', '272', '291']})

print(df)
df['x2'] = df['x2'].shift(1)
print(df)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your answer will be more helpful if you provide some explanation of how it should be used.

Comment: again you have lost one row #5 which OP clearly wants

Comment: This is a better solution because it can work for multiple columns as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Lets define the dataframe from your example by

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[206, 214], [226, 234], [245, 253], [265, 272], [283, 291]], 
    columns=[1, 2])
>>> df
     1    2
0  206  214
1  226  234
2  245  253
3  265  272
4  283  291
```

Then you could manipulate the index of the second column by

```
>>> df[2].index = df[2].index+1
```

and finally re-combine the single columns

```
>>> pd.concat([df[1], df[2]], axis=1)
       1      2
0  206.0    NaN
1  226.0  214.0
2  245.0  234.0
3  265.0  253.0
4  283.0  272.0
5    NaN  291.0
```

Perhaps not fast but simple to read. Consider setting variables for the column names and the actual shift required.

Edit: Generally shifting is possible by `df[2].shift(1)` as already posted however would that cut-off the carryover.

Comment: I wonder if there is a fast way to do this, and using a date index, Essentially you want to shift without truncating our series, and thus you must specify the additional index values. for a shift by one, you'd say something like series.shift(-1, fill=[datetime(<some date>)]). Is something like this possible?  Ah found it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36042804/how-to-shift-a-column-in-pandas-dataframe-without-losing-value

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to lose the columns you **shift past** the end of your dataframe, simply append the required number first:

```
    offset = 5
    DF = DF.append([np.nan for x in range(offset)])
    DF = DF.shift(periods=offset)
    DF = DF.reset_index() #Only works if sequential index
```

Answer (score 3):

I suppose imports

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

First append new row with `NaN, NaN,...` at the end of DataFrame (`df`).

```
s1 = df.iloc[0]    # copy 1st row to a new Series s1
s1[:] = np.NaN     # set all values to NaN
df2 = df.append(s1, ignore_index=True)  # add s1 to the end of df
```

It will create new DF df2. Maybe there is more elegant way but this works.

Now you can shift it:

```
df2.x2 = df2.x2.shift(1)  # shift what you want
```

Answer (score 2):

Trying to answer a personal problem and similar to yours I found on [Pandas Doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) what I think would answer this question:

> **DataFrame.shift**(periods=1, freq=None, axis=0)
> Shift index by desired number of periods with an optional time freq
>
> **Notes**
>
> If freq is specified then the index values are shifted but the data is not realigned. That is, use freq if you would like to extend the index when shifting and preserve the original data.

Hope to help future questions in this matter.

Answer (score 1):

```
df3

    1   108.210 108.231
2   108.231 108.156
3   108.156 108.196
4   108.196 108.074
... ... ...
2495    108.351 108.279
2496    108.279 108.669
2497    108.669 108.687
2498    108.687 108.915
2499    108.915 108.852

df3['yo'] = df3['yo'].shift(-1)

    yo  price
0   108.231 108.210
1   108.156 108.231
2   108.196 108.156
3   108.074 108.196
4   108.104 108.074
... ... ...
2495    108.669 108.279
2496    108.687 108.669
2497    108.915 108.687
2498    108.852 108.915
2499    NaN 108.852
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
df_ext = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(df.index[-1], periods=8, closed='right'))
df2 = pd.concat([df, df_ext], axis=0, sort=True)
df2["forecast"] = df2["some column"].shift(7)
```

Basically I am generating an empty dataframe with the desired index and then just concatenate them together. But I would really like to see this as a standard feature in pandas so I have [proposed an enhancement](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27091) to pandas.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to pandas, and I may not be understanding the question, but this solution worked for my problem:

```
# Shift contents of column 'x2' down 1 row
df['x2'] = df['x2'].shift()
```

Or, to create a new column with contents of 'x2' shifted down 1 row

```
# Create new column with contents of 'x2'  shifted down 1 row
df['x3'] = df['x2'].shift()
```

I had a read of the official docs for shift() while trying to figure this out, but it doesn't make much sense to me, and has no examples referencing this specific behavior.

Note that the last row of column 'x2' is effectively pushed off the end of the Dataframe. I expected shift() to have a flag to change this behaviour, but I can't find anything.