# How to shift a column in Pandas DataFrame without losing value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to shift a column in a Pandas DataFrame, but I haven't been able to find a method to do it without losing values.
(This post is quite similar to [How to shift a column in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982089/how-to-shift-a-column-in-pandas-dataframe?rq=1) but the validated answer doesn't give the desired output and I can't comment it).
Does anyone know how to do it?

```
##    x1   x2
##0  206  214
##1  226  234
##2  245  253
##3  265  272
##4  283  291
```

Desired output:

```
##    x1   x2
##0  206  nan
##1  226  214
##2  245  234
##3  265  253
##4  283  271
##5  nan  291
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to shift a column in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982089/how-to-shift-a-column-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `loc` to add a new blank row to the DataFrame, then perform the shift.

```
df.loc[max(df.index)+1, :] = None
df.x2 = df.x2.shift(1)
```

The code above assumes that your index is integer based, which is the pandas default.  If you're using a non-integer based index, replace `max(df.index)+1` with whatever you want the new last index to be.