# Pandas: Shift one column by other column value

Tags: python, pandas, shift

I'm trying to use one column's values to shift another columns values by that amount.  Pandas `shift()`, per the documentation, takes an integer, but is there a way to instead use a Series?

**Current Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                    'b':[0,0,0,0,4,4,4,0,0,0]})

df['a'] = df['a'].shift(df['b'])
```

...which is of course not working.

**Desired output:**

```
    a  b
0   1  0
1   2  0
2   3  0
3   4  0
4   1  4
5   2  4
6   3  4
7   8  0
8   9  0
9  10  0
```

If it makes it easier, the shift will always be the same, so theoretically the `'b'` series could be `True / False` or some other binary trigger, and the `.shift()` could still be an integer.  Feels a little hacky going that route, but it would get the job done.

Comment: Is it giving you a traceback? Or what is the current output?

Comment: @Adam, current traceback: `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`  I didn't really expect it to work, my code was more illustrative.  I'm playing with `.loc[]` and `df.index` but still not making headway.

Comment: shift simply moves all values in the column by a given period not a select amount. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982089/how-to-shift-a-column-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: @Adam - I'm not sure what to do with that comment.  I think you understand what I'm trying to achieve.  In fact, I don't need to use `.shift()`, just need to get the desired output.

Comment: I think I do I am just trying to figure out how to word it. lol

Comment: @Adam - right on.  Just figured it out and posted.  Thanks for helping.

Comment: The desired output you mention is the same as the input. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @COLDSPEED - take a closer look at indicies 4-6.

Comment: Uhm, so `df['a'] -= df['b']`?

Comment: @COLDSPEED - in this particular case that happens to work.  But if instead of `[1,2,3...]` it was `['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'...]`

Comment: How do you shift strings? NaN?

Answer (score 2):

we can use [`numba` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50972089/5741205):

```
from numba import jit

@jit
def dyn_shift(s, step):
    assert len(s) == len(step), "[s] and [step] should have the same length"
    assert isinstance(s, np.ndarray), "[s] should have [numpy.ndarray] dtype"
    assert isinstance(step, np.ndarray), "[step] should have [numpy.ndarray] dtype"
    N = len(s)
    res = np.empty(N, dtype=s.dtype)
    for i in range(N):
        res[i] = s[i-step[i]]
    return res
```

result:

```
In [302]: df['new'] = dyn_shift(df['a'].values, df['b'].values)
# NOTE: we should pass Numpy arrays:   ^^^^^^^         ^^^^^^^

In [303]: df
Out[303]:
    a  b  new
0   1  0    1
1   2  0    2
2   3  0    3
3   4  0    4
4   5  4    1
5   6  4    2
6   7  4    3
7   8  0    8
8   9  0    9
9  10  0   10
```

Comment: I have no doubt this is a great answer, but now I need to go down the `numba` rabbit hole!  Can you explain a little bit about what `numba` and `jit` do?  I'm completely unfamiliar.  Thanks.

Comment: @pshep123, I don't think I can explain better than [Pandas documentation does](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html#using-numba) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
df.loc[df['b'] == 4, 'a'] = df['a'].shift(4)
```

...this is the 'hacky' version I referred to above.  The first `4` is really just a trigger and the second `4` would be hard-coded.

Comment: But what if column `b` is variable? Taking into account that the shift is prioritized by row number; i.e. the first row has the highest priority in case of conflict and one row needs to replace the other.

Comment: @tiba - you're right. If it were more than binary, this would not be the solution.  However, per my original post, this solution fits my needs.  That said, if you have a solution that handles variables in `'b'`, then by all means, please post and I'll accept it.

Comment: @pshep123 If you have strings in `a`, and you try to shift by, say 1. What happens? Now, shift by 4. What happens? Are they NaN in both instances? Are other rows affected by how much `a` is shifted?

Comment: @COLDSPEED - there would only be `NaN`s if the shift went outside of the index.  If not, it would simply be replaced, so, to simplify `['apple','banana']` would become `['apple','apple']` in the event that the shift column were `[0,1]`.