# How to use the value of another column as a parameter of df.shift

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to get the value of the ‘shift’ column as an argument to the function shift

I try to

```
df['gg_shift']=df['gg'].shift(df['shift'])
```

but it doesn't work

expected result table

```
gg      bool    shift   gg_shift
0.88    FALSE   0   
0.87    TRUE    0   
0.94    FALSE   1       0.87
0.17    FALSE   2       0.87
0.92    TRUE    0   
0.51    FALSE   1       0.92
0.1     TRUE    0   
0.88    FALSE   1       0.1
0.36    FALSE   2       0.1
0.14    TRUE    0
```

Comment: I found someone else's solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50970476/comparing-values-from-pandas-data-frame-column-using-offset-values-from-another/50972089#50972089

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be misinterpreting your logic, but it looks like you want to get the `gg` values of the previous True for all False.

If this is the case you do not need to use the `shift` column, simply [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) and [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) the data:

```
df['gg_shift'] = df['gg'].where(df['bool']).ffill().mask(df['bool'])
```

output:

```
     gg   bool  shift  gg_shift
0  0.88  False      0       NaN
1  0.87   True      0       NaN
2  0.94  False      1      0.87
3  0.17  False      2      0.87
4  0.92   True      0       NaN
5  0.51  False      1      0.92
6  0.10   True      0       NaN
7  0.88  False      1      0.10
8  0.36  False      2      0.10
9  0.14   True      0       NaN
```

Comment: This is a good idea, my logic is that if I can get the position based on shift, I can get any column at that position

Answer (score 1):

Because only scalar is possible pass to [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) get unique values of `shift` without `0` (no shift) and assign only match condition:

```
for x in df.loc[df['shift'].ne(0), 'shift'].unique():
    m = df['shift'].eq(x)
    df.loc[m, 'gg_shift'] = df['gg'].shift(x)
    
print (df)
     gg   bool  shift  gg_shift
0  0.88  False      0       NaN
1  0.87   True      0       NaN
2  0.94  False      1      0.87
3  0.17  False      2      0.87
4  0.92   True      0       NaN
5  0.51  False      1      0.92
6  0.10   True      0       NaN
7  0.88  False      1      0.10
8  0.36  False      2      0.10
9  0.14   True      0       NaN
```