# How can I use pandas rolling function without aggregated function?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame similar to this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]})
```

I want to use rolling function in pandas, but I don't need the aggregated function (sum, mean, min, max,...) after rolling. I need data for each window.

I can develop a sliding window myself, but my question is about rolling function. is it possible to have something similar to this by using rolling function in pandas.

when I use the following function

```
w = df.rolling(2)
```

I received the following result:

```
Rolling [window=2,center=False,axis=0]
```

while I need this:

```
w = [[0 , 1]
    [1 , 2]
    [2 , 3]
    [3 , 4]]
```

Comment: What you want is [How to shift a column in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982089/how-to-shift-a-column-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

Since pandas `1.1` rolling objects are iterable, so you can just do:

```
w = list(df.rolling(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `np.stride_tricks`:

```
import numpy as np
as_strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided  
win = 2
v = as_strided(df.B, (len(df) - (win - 1), win), (df.B.values.strides * 2))
print(v)
```

Comment: @MSN try this one.

Comment: so according to your answer i cannot use rolling function in this regard?

Comment: May Be it is possible with rolling function @MSN

Comment: be careful while using `as_strided`. See warnings in the documentation.