# Filling a new column with values from a different column

Tags: python, pandas

Supposing I have a dataframe like so :
[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvi0P.png)

If I have to make a new column, which has the values from column 3 like so
4
N/A
-1.135632
-1.044236
1.071804
0.271860
-1.087401
0.524988
-1.039268
0.844885
-1.469388
-0.968914

i.e, entry 1 of column 4 is filled with entry 0 of column 3, entry 2 of column 4 is filled with entry 1 of column 3 and so on...until the nth entry in the 4th column is filled with the (n-1)th entry of the 3rd column

Comment: Please include your data in the body of your question as text so it can be copy-and-pasted and searched to help us help you; you can wrap text with three back-tics (`) to create a code block to format it nicely

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to shift a column in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982089/how-to-shift-a-column-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df['column_4'] = df['column_3'].shift(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [`Series.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)?

```py
df[4] = df[3].shift()
```